# Error en archivo php para buscador telefónico

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Hola estoy haciendo un buscador telefónico pero el navegador me indica qje tengo un error en mi archivo load.php en la línea 3 (el require) [image: el error es en el require 'config.php']
Y no se a que se debe , he revisado el código muchas veces y no le veo [image: este es el error que me da en el navegador]

Comment: hola, el codigo se coloca en formato de texto, no imagen al igual que el error, te imagina que tenemos que transcribir todo para intentar ayudarte ...

Comment: Otra cosa es que el "SELECT" necesita un espacio al final asi: "SELECT " para separalo de las columnas .. es lo que dice el error que esta haciendo mal ...

Comment: Bueno repare el error del select como me dijiste,  pero me cintinua el error en la columna 12 que es la de $resultado = $conn->query($sql)

Comment: Perdona que lo haya puesto en foto , fue la manera que se me ocurrió más rápida, saludos

Comment: Pues podría ser algo parecido. ¿Porqué hay un salto de línea antes del FROM? ¿Has probado a quitarlo?

Comment: Si , ya probe pero sigue dando el mismo error =(

Comment: No he podido mostrar los valores de la tabla en mi base de datos debido a esto

Comment: Hola que te sale de error en la linea 12? Tal vez allí sea algo de la conexion a MySQL

Answer (score 1):

el error de la foto, como bien ya te han comentado es por el "SELECTid", faltaba un espacio después del "SELECT"...

Echandole un vistazo a la sentencia de tu consulta, veo que concatenas la primera variable de tu sentencia pero no la segunda, aunque no debería ser un problema.

```
    "SELECT ".implode(", ", $columns)." FROM ".$table ;
```

Esa debería ser una sentencia correcta sql. Si pudieses subir una foto de ese segundo error que comentas estaría genial